# Cannot find Docker package in RHEL7 repository

Tags: rhel, docker, repository, container

According to Red Hat documentation, the repository rhel-7-workstation-extras-rpms should contain Docker (apparently it was originally only in server package but now is in both), but it does not appear to be present. I am working in an isolated environment (without internet access) and my application will be deployed under the same conditions, so I need to understand how I can install a container platform on my development machine that will work in production, too. Can anyone give me some advice?
As always, thank you for your time and attention.